# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.cannot be cast to java.lang.Long while starting server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am upgrading hibernate version from 4.1.9 to 5.4.11 and mssql-jdbc version to 7.2.2.jre8 . I am trying connecting to MS sql server

But while starting the server , I am getting below error message

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the
>   following failure: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.Long at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118) at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77) at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:74) at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.handleThrowable(NewPooledConnection.java:505)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getLong(NewProxyResultSet.java:491)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetStartValueSize(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:129)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:59)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:155)
>   … 127 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Long at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getLong(SQLServerResultSet.java:2328)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getLong(NewProxyResultSet.java:477)
>   … 132 more
>
> Can you please help me in resolving this issue ?

Comment: Can you show use some code? What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: One of your entity class fields is defined as Long when the corresponding column in the database is decimal.

Comment: @Simon Martinelli  - Hibernate version is 5.4.11 and mssql-jdbc version is 7.2.2.jre8.
 I am getting this error while fetching the SequenceInformation from the MS sql database.
I am setting hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate .

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am getting this error during Hibernate schema validation

Comment: As @AlwaysLearning said you there is a missmatch between the database type and the entity. Can you show table and entity code?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli Table Name - INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES.

Created a sequence using the below query.

CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE] AS [numeric](28, 0) 
START WITH 1015377 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 
MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 CACHE  20;

Comment: And how does the Entity look like?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES is a database table. we do not have an entity.

Comment: Sure but you have entits that use @GeneratedVAlue

Comment: @Omkar123 Have you resolved this? I am getting the same error when upgrading to the same version of Hibernate and mssql-jdbc